# Why does the Scala compiler differently treat these two code blocks?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

***This compiles***.  (Note that `implicit val subscriptionReads` composes `emailIdReads` and `intervalReads` declared **outside** the implicit, whereas `subscriptionWrites` is composed of `Writes` declared **inside** the implicit.)

```
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json.Writes._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Subscription(emailId: String, interval: String)

object Subscription {

  val emailIdReads: Reads[String]  = (JsPath \ "emailId").read[String]

  val intervalReads: Reads[String] = (JsPath \ "interval").read[String]

  implicit val subscriptionReads: Reads[Subscription] = (
      emailIdReads and
      intervalReads
    )(Subscription.apply _)

  implicit val subscriptionWrites: Writes[Subscription] = (
    (JsPath \ "emailId").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "interval").write[String]
    )(unlift(Subscription.unapply))
}
```

Yet the code below  -- where the two `Writes` values are declared ***outside*** the implicit -- ***does not compile***, yielding the error message: "value `and` is not a member of play.api.libs.json.Writes[String]."

```
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json.Writes._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Subscription(emailId: String, interval: String)

object Subscription {

  val emailIdReads: Reads[String]  = (JsPath \ "emailId").read[String]

  val intervalReads: Reads[String] = (JsPath \ "interval").read[String]

  implicit val subscriptionReads: Reads[Subscription] = (
      emailIdReads and
      intervalReads
    )(Subscription.apply _)

  val emailIdWrites: Writes[String]  = (JsPath \ "emailId").write[String]

  val intervalWrites: Writes[String] = (JsPath \ "interval").write[String]

  implicit val subscriptionWrites: Writes[Subscription] = (
      emailIdWrites and
      intervalWrites
    )(unlift(Subscription.unapply))

}
```

What am I missing?  Why can't I substitute equals-for-equals?  Moreover, why can I do it with `Reads` but not `Writes`.  I'd like to *understand* why this doesn't work.

The relevant definition of `and` is set out in `play.api.libs.functional`.

```
package play.api.libs.functional

import scala.language.higherKinds

case class ~[A, B](_1: A, _2: B)

trait FunctionalCanBuild[M[_]] {

  def apply[A, B](ma: M[A], mb: M[B]): M[A ~ B]

}

class FunctionalBuilderOps[M[_], A](ma: M[A])(implicit fcb: FunctionalCanBuild[M]) {

  def ~[B](mb: M[B]): FunctionalBuilder[M]#CanBuild2[A, B] = {
    val b = new FunctionalBuilder(fcb)
    new b.CanBuild2[A, B](ma, mb)
  }

  def and[B](mb: M[B]): FunctionalBuilder[M]#CanBuild2[A, B] = this.~(mb)
}

/* Additional arities elided */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to dig a little and the reason is actually in this file where the required implicit is defined:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/26a9c7625d6c482abf1c6ecedacff34d670bee01/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Writes.scala

It is defined for the type OWrites not Writes. And what you are getting from .write[String] is actually of type OWrites[String]. The reason it does not work, is, that you are explicitly specifying the wider type Writes.

Comment: Do you have a line number where it's defined for OWrites?  (I can't find it in the Writes file that you linked.).